# egit for eclipse: How do I put my existing project in the clone of my buddies repo?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

My buddy gave me his git address for the project we are going to work on. In Eclipse using egit I cloned his branch.

So now in my Git view I have my own repository I created of an existing project. I want this existing project to be on my buddies branch so we can both check it out and have it in our repo.

Unfortunately I am using Windows to do this because we are developing a game and I do all of the art & animation in addition to programming. I would feel much more comfortable on the cmd line than using this plugin..

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notion of repo and branch are quite different.
If you have a clone of our buddy's repo, you can work on a branch named like the one your buddy uses (by default '`master`' if he hadn't created any other), and everything you will push will be added/merged to the remote branch in the remote repo.

For more on Egit, see this "[Git with Eclipse (EGit) - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html)", and check if yuo can push at least one file, that your colleague will be able to pull from the remote repo and see directly in his branch.